# Activate the delete key from the code

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

i have a code in android studio , in the code i have an EditText

```
  <EditText
    android:background="#90fff7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:maxLength="50"
    />
```

and button

```
       <Button
        android:background="@drawable/ic_if_delete"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="0"

        />
```

i want that when i tap on the button - the event of click on delete key(from the defult keyboard) will activiate .

for exemple if i click on *my* button in the edit text the first letter delete like i click on the delete key on the defult keyboard

dont offer me to delete the last char from the string , this is dont what i looking for, i simply search for way to Simulate pressing the delete key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manipulate text inside edit text

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int length = editText.getSelectionStart();
        if (length > 0) {
            editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
            edittext.setSelection(length-1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i can do it, but then i need to take care of the cursur and its complicated , so i dont. i need what i say in my first ask, thankyou

Comment: Then You Can Check The Updated Answer

Comment: i mean the situation like the cursur at the middle of the string , so he need to be visible and delete one char of the screen , if the cursur in the end of the string so he need to be invisible and delete one char from the string. things like that i cant take care of , just the Simulate pressing the delete key can do it

Comment: Got Your Point!!

Comment: check the  updated answer

Comment: its almost perfect ! but when the cursur in the midlle of the string and i write somthing its add in the end not in the middle

Comment: So you just need to set the cursor location again 
I have updated the code please confirm

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to both view like on `android:id="@+id/btn_delete"` and button like `android:id="@+id/edit_query"`

set on click listener on button

```
 final EditText editQuery = findViewById(R.id.edit_query);
    Button btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editQuery.setText(""); // if want to clear all

            String value = editQuery.getText().toString();

            value=value.subString(0,value.length()-1);
            editQuery.setText(value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what if edit text is empty??

Comment: because i want to Simulate pressing the delete key i dont need to take care of this but i need to know how to Simulate pressing the delete key